# Does running a SKTransition on a SKScene destroy the origin SKScene?

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

Does running a SKTransition on a SKScene destroy the origin SKScene?

For example:

```
 SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition revealWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionDown duration:1.0];
    GameConfigScene *newScene = [[GameConfigScene alloc] initWithSize: CGSizeMake(1024,768)]];
//  Optionally, insert code to configure the new scene.
    [self.scene.view presentScene: newScene transition: reveal];
```

Will the current scene be destroyed when the transition is executed? Or is still on memory? Has the new scene a reference to the old scene?

Comment: could you show the property self.scene in your question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets assume that your `scene` property is like this `@property(weak) SKScene *scene;` then the answer is YES, will be destroyed when you present another scene or pop it from the stack. 
If you have your property like `@property(strong) SKScene *scene`, then the answer is NO, your scene will stay in memory until you do this `self.scene = nil;`
But remember that the `SKView` retinas the presented scene so you should nil it somewhere in your app to avoid retain cycles (when you have strong property).

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the previous answers, if you're still unsure and want to easily check when/if the original scene is deallocated, you can do this simply by overriding the `dealloc` method and logging a message/setting a breakpoint to see if it was invoked by the runtime. Put this in your old scene:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"Old scene deallocated");
}
```

By default (if not strongly referenced elsewhere), it will be deallocated *after* the entire transition has finished and the new scene has fully moved to your view. So, for the duration of the transition, both scenes will exist in the memory.

Answer (score 1):

ARC will deallocated the old scene, unless you specifically strong referenced it elsewhere.

It is not referenced in the new scene by default.