# Is it possible to push a Scene on top of another in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skscene

When transitioning between SKScenes, is it possible to keep the first scene around and push the second scene on top of the first scene, so that it is possible to return to the first scene? 
I.e. does something like pushviewcontroller exist for skscenes?

Comment: You could push to another viewController that contained another SKScene.
Your SKScene is inside a SKView that is inside a UIVIewController. You could go to another ViewControler using a push and present another SKScene. 

You should check the memory impact of doing this... but is possible.

Comment: If by keeping around you mean retaining, then yes, of course. Just keep a strong reference somewhere to the first scene. Perhaps take a look at [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879747/does-running-a-sktransition-on-a-skscene-destroy-the-origin-skscene) about using an [SKTransition](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTransition_Ref/index.html).

Comment: do you mean that the first scene should have a strong reference to itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You just need to have a strong reference to the currently disabled scene, for instance in a property of the view controller, to prevent it from deallocating and to be able to present it again when you "pop" the "pushed" scene.

See Kobold Kit's implementation of pushScene/popScene in its SKView subclass, which uses a regular array to hold on to the scenes on the "push stack": https://github.com/KoboldKit/KoboldKit/blob/master/KoboldKit/KoboldKitFree/Framework/View/KKView.m